# Macro with if inside?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to do something like this? Look at this code:

```
#define MyMacro(...) SomeFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Now, I would like the 2nd parameter to be conditionally compiled:

```
#define MyMacro(...) SomeFunction(arg1,
#if CONDITION
    arg2,
#endif
    arg3)
```

This actually doesn't compile but it shows what I want to achieve - when `CONDITION` is satisfied I want `MyMacro` to use the 3 argument version of `SomeFunction` and the 2 argument one otherwise.

Of course, here I could just explicitly write both function calls but in my program I actually have 3 "conditional" parameters which would give me 8 combinations.

Comment: hmm i would do it like #ifdef condition #define mymacro something #else #define mymacro something else #endif

Comment: As I wrote - I know I can do that but with 8 combinations (and I have more than 1 such function) I would **really** like to avoid it.

Comment: You can have a helper macro that conditionally selects the args.

Comment: And how would that look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#if CONDITION
#define ARG2 arg2,
#else
#define ARG2
#endif

#define MyMacro(...) SomeFunction(arg1, ARG2 arg3)
```

Comment: This is the kind of solution when you see which you think "Why haven't I thought of that?!". Seems so obvious now. :)

Comment: @NPS I wouldn't say it's "obvious", and I wouldn't call it very maintainable either unless you really keep the conditions and the macro definition tightly coupled in the source (otherwise someone (including yourself a few months down the line) might come and say "hey why is there no comma there?", add the comma and cause weird errors). There was another answer (unfortunately now deleted) that I thought was much clearer. It defined the `MyMacro` in the condition instead.

Answer (score 1):

look at boost::preprocessor for more details

the idea is the following:

```
#include <iostream>

#define SELECT0(ARG1, ARG2) ARG1
#define SELECT1(ARG1, ARG2) ARG2
#define SELECT(COND_0_OR_1, ARG1, ARG2) SELECT##COND_0_OR_1(ARG1, ARG2)

const char * s = 
SELECT(0, "arg1", "arg2");

int main(void) {

  std::cout<<s;  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but this selects 1 of 2 arguments. How do I conditionally **remove** an argument?

Comment: make an empty define:
#define SELECT0(ARG1, ARG2)

Comment: or use SELECT(CONDITION, ,arg2)

Comment: +1 because it solves my problem but I chose Michael Burr's answer because it's simpler (and hence better).